# Remove item with header from angular material list

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have material list with header. Similar item grouped under header.
I added remove button also.in it. If I remove last item from list then the header also should remove. What I tried is below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-brenrk?file=app/app.component.ts

But it is not getting removed . Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close to do it.

This is your application corrected and working:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-list-bufnqr

To explain, it's better to call `element.category` in place of `element['category']` and so on for every fields and you need to delete `element.category` and not `element.name` at the end when you remove the last item.

Comment: Thanks buddy it helps

Answer (score 2):

By default, Angular's change detection loops through your array, and check if there was a reference change to the previous change. Now, you did not change any reference, only a property of these objects.
Since the object reference in your array does not change, Angular does not recognise that there was a change. I recommend using immutable operators, which does not mutate the previous object but creates a now one:

```
removeFromList(obj){
  this.valmap = this.valmap
    .map(element => {
      return {category: element.category, values: element.values.filter(fruit => fruit.name !== obj.name)}
  })
    .filter(element => element.values.length > 0)
}
```

Your other choice is to introduce [`trackBy`](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf) in your ˙ngFor`, to tell Angular when a property changed.

Comment: Tried Ur answer but not working. Can u post as a stackblitz

Comment: can u post as an answer bin stackblitz